# Wordpress shows all posts using the_content()

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to work with wordpress.In our home page how can we show all posts description with some lines and a more link.
I am try it with
 `the_content(__('(more...)'));` .
But it is not working.Which shows full story directly.The 'more...' is not working..Can anybody help me please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--more-->
```

Put this (in html view) between your description (excerpt) and your full story.

Some more Information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt